# How to know if cronjob is failing (running a python command)

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

When I run this command, the output message is being saved into ok.txt:

```
 /home/admin/virtualenvs/x.com/bin/python /home/admin/www/x.com/x/app/manage.py help | tee ok.txt
```

I have this cronjob:

```
* * * * * /home/admin/virtualenvs/x.com/bin/python /home/admin/www/x.com/x/app/manage.py help | tee ok.txt
```

But nothing is saved to ok.txt

When I see the cron log

```
> sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog

May 10 22:16:01 localhost CRON[23397]: (admin) CMD (/home/admin/virtualenvs/x.com/bin/python /home/admin/www/x.com/x/app/manage.py help | tee ok.txt)
```

No hints here, what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: You should receive mail if an error occurs while running your crontab. Make sure you read your local mail or redirect your local mail to an account you read. A possibility is that this `virtualenvs` is not available from cron; you should explain what it is.

Comment: why want to close it? if its fully related with programming, cuz developers complements their code with automated jobs!. "devs write cronjobs" - and the erased answer was correct! why did you close it admin?

Comment: Just because you happen to be a developer doesn't make this is a programming question. This is a user question, so I voted to migrate it to [Super User](http://superuser.com/), which would be appropriate. I have nothing to do with the answer being deleted. IIRC there was a major error in it, so maybe the author realized this and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

try with this :

```
* * * * * /home/admin/virtualenvs/x.com/bin/python /home/admin/www/x.com/x/app/manage.py help > /tmp/ok.txt 2&>1
```

it should put all outputs (stderr and stdout) into your ok.txt file

Comment: To support the above, always use full paths in crontab entries, who knows what the working dir is, and even if you do know don't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

first i see that you don't have the correct syntax for crontab:

```
Example of job definition:
.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

you are missing the user-name.

And the second thing. Don't assume that your .bashrc is loaded. In cron you just get the environment that is defined on top of the file. So if your script is using something that you have defined in your bashrc then it might be, that it doesn't execute correctly.